# Whats wrong on my Postgres insert or update query

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, postgresql-9.5, sqlfiddle

I want to insert or update data to a table. The column "Group" is UNIQUE and the ID of the group should remain constant.

there Is a Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/551ea/3

- on Insert, everything is okay
- also the Update works for "Group" = 'TEST01'

But when I insert a new group and then update, the ID changes (press multiple "Run SQL")

This is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO GROUPS ("GROUP", SERVER, PATH, SHARE)
VALUES ('TEST04', 4, 4, 4)
ON CONFLICT("GROUP") DO UPDATE
SET SERVER = 11,
    PATH = 11, 
    SHARE = 11
WHERE GROUPS."GROUP" = 'TEST01'
```

The ID will be used in other tables, this should only be created once for the first entry.

and this is the general structure:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE gid START 1;
CREATE TABLE GROUPS (
  ID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gid') PRIMARY KEY,
  "GROUP" VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  SERVER integer,
  PATH integer,
  SHARE integer
);
```

Comment: I think that this is a SQLFiddle problem, not a problem with your SQL. Run your script with a "normal" SQL client against a database that his not shared on the internet. The code is fine and will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/551ea/27)

Each time there is a conflict on insert - the sequence value is discarded and `ON UPDATE` requests a new value. So initially you start with 1, then you insert 3 tuples so the final value of the sequence would be 3. Then you try to insert a new tuple but there is a conflict - so the value of sequence is now 4. Then you try to insert a new tuple - and it gets a value of 5 for the sequence.

If you continue to run the 2 inserts the sequence will continue to increment. SQLfiddle probably uses persistent connections or some connection pooling which does not properly reset the sequence when rebuilding the schema.